# Make itemize/enumerate invisible

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I would like to make a itemize/enumerate environment invisible/white.

The reason is that I'm adding new bullet points successively, and don't want the existing text to move around.

If I have standard text I just make the yet-to-be-displayed texts white, so the formatting remains the same across successive slides. I would like to do the same for lists.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm also happy with built-in support of this in beamer (as suggested by Ingmar), but then I would also need to hide the bullet points themselves, not only the text.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us some code, particularly which class you are using. If this is for presentations, maybe `Beamer`? It has built-in support for this kind of thing. But yes, you could assign the background color to your bullet points, too, if you really wanted.

Comment: Thanks; now updated!

Comment: Please add an MWE (minimal working example) to show what you want. As Ingmar pointed out, there is built-in support for this via beamer overlay. For instance, you could use, `\textcolor{white}{\textcolor<+->{black}{Your text}}`.

Comment: Please post a _full_ MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass{beamer}`, ends with `\end{document}` and actually compiles …

Comment: I added a full MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item A
\pause  \item B
\pause  \item C
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Easiest way I can think of. There are others.

Comment: Excellent, that does it!